# Login System: How to return the value of an element's parameter in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, parameters, linked-list, get

I have 2 members in my ArrayList.
Each element has 3 parameters.
I want to return a single parameter of that element.
When 1 member signs in, I want to retrieve their name & print it out on line:
System.out.print("Session Admin: " + members.get(0) + " - Menu Commands (C/R/U/D/V/M/X): ");

when I use members.get(0), it returns an email address of 1 person, no matter who has logged in.

How do I match the name to the logged in user, and return their name?

Thank you

```
import java.util.*;

public class Session {
private SuperMarkets SuperMarkets;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Membership Management System:");
    System.out.println("L- Login\nX- Exit");
    new Session().use();
}

private LinkedList<SuperMarket> members = new LinkedList<SuperMarket>();


public Session() {
    members.add(new SuperMarket("Jane Tyler", "jane.tyler@uts.com", "super123"));
    members.add(new SuperMarket("John Smith", "john.smith@uts.com", "user222"));


}

private SuperMarket member(String email) {
    for(SuperMarket member : members)
        if(member.hasEmail(email))
            return member;
    return null;

}


private SuperMarket memberp(String password) {
    for(SuperMarket member : members)
        if(member.hasPassword(password))
            return member;
    return null;

}


public void use() {
    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'X') {
        switch (choice) {
            case 'L': login(); break;
            case 'C': addMembership(); break;
            case 'U': updateMembership(); break;
            case 'D': deleteMembership(); break;
            case 'V': viewMemberships(); break;
            case 'M': mmsMenu(); break;
            default: help();
            if ((choice == 'l')) {
                System.out.println("Membership Management System:");
                System.out.println("L- Login\nX- Exit");

            } 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nSession Terminated!");
    
}

private char readChoice() {
    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Command (L/X): ");
    return In.next().charAt(0);
}

private String readEmail() {
    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Email: ");
    return In.nextLine();
}

private String readPassword() {
    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Password: ");
    return In.nextLine();
}

public void login() {
    SuperMarket member = member(readEmail()); 
    SuperMarket memberp = memberp(readPassword());
    if ((memberp != null) && (member != null)) {
        new Session().adminMenu();
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect SuperMarket details!");

    }

}


public void adminMenu() { 
    System.out.println("Admin Menu:");
    System.out.println("C- Add Membership");
    System.out.println("R- View Membership");
    System.out.println("U- Update Membership");
    System.out.println("D- Delete Membership");
    System.out.println("V- View Memberships");
    System.out.println("M- MMS Menu");
    System.out.println("X- Logout");
    System.out.print("Session Admin: " + members.get(0) + " - Menu Commands (C/R/U/D/V/M/X): ");



}
public void addMembership() {

}
public void viewMembership() {
    
}
public void updateMembership() {
    
}
public void deleteMembership() {
    
}
public void viewMemberships() {
    
}
public void mmsMenu() {
    
}

public void help() {

}

  }
```

**Second Class:**

```
public class SuperMarket {

private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private Memberships Memberships;
private MMSLog MMSLog;

public SuperMarket(String name, String email, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;

}


public String login(String email) {
    return email;

}

public boolean hasEmail(String email) { 
    return email.equals(this.email);
}




public boolean hasPassword(String password) {
    return password.equals(this.password);
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return email;
}




 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning just the email, it's returning the entire object.
The thing here is on `ToString` method in `SuperMarket`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return email;
}
```

In your code, you are doing:

```
System.out.print("Session Admin: " + members.get(0) + " - Menu Commands (C/R/U/D/V/M/X): ");
```

which internally is calling `toString()` method.

Change the `toString()` method to match your needs.